# javascript, get size of a background scaled with contain property

Tags: javascript, background, scale, contain

I've seen a few posts here trying to answer this question and I tried using the codes given as answers but haven't been able to get it to work, so I must be doing something wrong. Basically I have a div with a background-image with the CSS property "background-size: contain". I want to get the dimensions of the scaled background. Here is my code, mostly copied from another post here, with some things changed to match my div's names:

```
var elem = document.querySelector("#enlarged-inner .image-bg");
```

function getBackgroundSize(elem) {

```
elem = document.querySelector("#enlarged-inner .image-bg");

//get original background size

var computedStyle = getComputedStyle(elem);
var img = new Image;
img.src = computedStyle.backgroundImage.replace(/url\((['"])?(.*?)\1\)/gi, '$2');
var imgW = parseInt(img.width, 10);
var imgH = parseInt(img.height, 10);

//get scaled size

var newW = parseInt(computedStyle.width, 10);
var newH = parseInt(computedStyle.height, 10);
var scaledW = 0;
var scaledH = 0;

    scaledW = imgW / imgH * newH;
    scaledH = imgH / imgW * newW; 

} 

window.onresize = function(){ getBackgroundSize(elem); }
```

Its able to get the original (unscaled) size of the background image just fine, so I atleast know that the first half of the code is working. But the second part, the important part, doesn't seem to do anything. I've been testing it by changing a test divs innerHTML to the new variables:

```
document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = newW + " , " + newH;
```

I'm new to javascript and not great at math so I'm sure theres probably something I'm just not understanding correctly here.

EDIT: the code above has been updated a little and heres some more explanation.

[image]

So in this picture the blue box is a scalable div that contains the div with the background. Its height and width are set with vh and vw.
The gray box represents the background image itself, with its size set to contain. In the updated code above, newW and newH give me the dimensions of the blue box, no matter how its scaled. imgW and imgH give me the original unscaled dimensions of the background. I want scaledW and scaledH to return the scaled size of the gray box, but my math doesnt seem to work out.

Answer (score 0):

I can't test it right now but I think that the variables you're modifying (newW and newH) are passed by value. So, you actually don't update your image's size. You'll probably need to use these variables to update your image's size, maybe with:
`img.width = newW`  etc

Comment: the problem is that newH and newW don't actually compute the scaled height and width. They just return the original, unscaled, size of the background.

Comment: If debug your code with the browser's console, do you enter your `getBackgroundSize` function?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a simpler way to achieve what I wanted. Basically what I was trying to do was have a div with an image in it, that I could scale to any size, and the entire image would always fit inside the div (similar to the background-size contain property), and the images would always maintain their original aspect ratio. In my particular case instead of a div, its the size of the full window, and I found it to be easier to work with images in img tags instead of backgrounds. Heres the code:

```
function getBackgroundSize(elem) {

elem = document.querySelector("#enlarged-inner img");

var imgW = elem.naturalWidth;
var imgH = elem.naturalHeight;
var newW = window.innerWidth;
var newH = window.innerHeight;

var imgRatio = imgW / imgH;
var newRatio = newW / newH;

var scaledW = 0;
var scaledH = 0;

if (imgRatio > newRatio) {
    scaledW = newW;
    scaledH = imgH * newW / imgW; }
else {
    scaledW = imgW * newH / imgH;
    scaledH = newH; }

document.querySelector("#enlarged-inner img").style.width  = scaledW;
document.querySelector("#enlarged-inner img").style.height = scaledH;

}
```

I basically just found the unscaled height and width of the image, and the dimensions of the containing div (the window in my case), and then found their ratios of width over height. I'm not so good at math but atleast in the examples I tried to work out, if the W/H of the image was larger than W/H of the window, it would mean the image's width would be defined by the width of the window. And then the correct height of the image could be found with some simple math.